# Selective rearrangement of columns in XMLListCollection not working

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, flex4

I am trying to selectively rearrange columns in my XMLListCollection but for some reasons it is not working.

As an example, say my array is - `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]`. I am trying to shift 9th column to 2nd column. So my output shall be like this `[1, 9, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10]`.

I have tried the below code to achieve my result.

```
model.columns = new XMLListCollection(event.payload.Columns.Column); 

// Selective re-arrangment
// Storing 9 col in backup variable
Var backUp:XMLListCollection = model.columns[9];
// Removing item from column 9
model.columns.removeItemAt(9);
// Inserting backup variable at desired index
model.columns.addItemAt(backUp,2)

// Code for rendering each column
for each( var col:XML in model.columns){
    if(col.@visible == "Y"){
            var dataGridColumn:FlexDataGridColumn = new FlexDataGridColumn();
            dataGridColumn.headerText = col.@display_nm;
            dataGridColumn.dataField = '@'+col.@variable;
            view.adjustmentModuleColumns.addColumn( dataGridColumn);
            view.adjustmentsDataGrid.reDraw();
     }
}
```

For some reasons above code is not working as expected. Please suggest.

Comment: can you edit your question and expand on the explanation of the issue you are seeing?

Comment: A sample of the input, the current output, and the desired output would be most helpful.

Comment: Have you tried the `Sort` and `SortField` bits as shown in the [Sorting and filtering data in an XMLListCollection](http://blog.flexexamples.com/2007/08/22/sorting-and-filtering-data-in-an-xmllistcollection/) sample?

Comment: » the current output

Comment: This problem is fixed. The problem was in  this line. Var backUp:XMLListCollection = model.columns[9];. I have just replaced this line code into this.  Var backUp:XML = model.columns[9];